# How to access members of a struct inside QList

Tags: qt

I have a struct like this:

```
struct Flow
{
  QLayoutItem * item;
  bool shown;
};
```

I would like to use a `QList` for this struct like this:

```
QList<Flow> itemList;
```

The following function gives a compile error:

```
void FlowLayout::add(QLayoutItem *item)
{
  itemList.item = item;
  itemList.shown = true;
  itemList.append(itemlist);
}
```

The error is:

`class "QList<FlowLayout::Flow *>" has no member "item"`

How to access item member and append it to the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is clear enough: `QList` indeed doesn't have `item` member. Create a `Flow` object, fill it and put into the list:

```
void FlowLayout::add(QLayoutItem *item)
{
  Flow flow;
  flow.item = item;
  flow.shown = true;
  itemList.append(flow);
}
```

Comment: In Qt, working with automatic objects in this manner is a bad idea. The list should be `QList<Flow*>` instead, and the objects should be created with `new`.

Comment: Please explain why it is a bad idea.

Comment: Oops, `Flow` is not a QObject. Please ignore.  (But to answer the question anyway: because parents call `delete` on their children. Sometimes, Qt widgets call `delete` on themselves.)

Comment: is there a way to find a node of the list by lets say `qFind(itemList.begin().shown, itemList.end()..shown, tmpFlowObject.shown)` ?